# How to use of XmlGregorianCalendar with fromJson and toJson methods of gson?

Tags: jaxb, gson

The theme of my project is to give XML format of data and get Json format using google-gson and I have JAXB generated java POJOs from XML schema in which I have a variable of XMLGregorianCalendar datatype.

I give the following input of XML and get the json format from the gson.toJson() method;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmpRequest xmlns="http://java.com/Employee">
<EmplIn>
<EmpID>12</EmpID>
<Empname>sara</Empname>
<Designation>SA</Designation>
<DOJ>2002-05-30T09:30:10+06:00</DOJ>
</EmplIn>
</EmpRequest>
```

But in the output, I got the following.

```
{"emplIn":{"empID":"12","empname":"sara","designation":"SA","doj":{}}}
```

I surfed google and got the suggestion of adding  in the xml schema and changing the XmlGregorianCalendar datatype with string. But I dont want to achieve it from both the ways.

I mean how to get the proper output with the XmlGregorianCalendar datatype through fromJson and toJson methods of gson?

Thank you so much,
Harish Raj.

Comment: You could use EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) to convert your objects to/from both XML and JSON.  Let me know if you are interested in this approach:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/binding-to-json-xml-geocode-example.html

Comment: YEs, Blaise, I would love to if it works for <xs:dateTime> with the XmlGregorianCalendar datatype.

Comment: Blaise, Can you explain me little futher with an example, so that I could implement it? I am confused of how to implement it which you provided. :(

Comment: I have added an answer that demonstrates how MOXy could be used to implement your use case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hopefully, This can fix my issue of using [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

(The following should be added in where we create the object of Gson)

Step 1:

```
    Gson gson =
        new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(XMLGregorianCalendar.class,
                                              new XGCalConverter.Serializer()).registerTypeAdapter(XMLGregorianCalendar.class,
                                                                                                   new XGCalConverter.Deserializer()).create();
```

Step 2: And we need to create the XGCalConverter Class as like the following.

```
 import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
 import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
 import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
 import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
 import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
 import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;

 import java.lang.reflect.Type;

 import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
 import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

  public class XGCalConverter
  {
   public static class Serializer implements JsonSerializer
   {
    public Serializer()
    {
     super();
    }

    public JsonElement serialize(Object t, Type type,
                             JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext)
    {
     XMLGregorianCalendar xgcal=(XMLGregorianCalendar)t;
     return new JsonPrimitive(xgcal.toXMLFormat());
    }
  }
    public static class Deserializer implements JsonDeserializer
    {

      public Object deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type,
                               JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext)
      {
          try
           {
              return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(jsonElement.getAsString());
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
               ex.printStackTrace();
               return null;
           }
         }
       }
     }
```

Comment: This method makes my serialized epoch times wrapped in quotes.  Any ideas to get them as working numbers?

Comment: Regarding the code in this answer: You probably have to use [`GsonBuilder.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(java.lang.Class,java.lang.Object)) instead of `registerTypeAdapter` because `XMLGregorianCalendar` is an abstract class with subclasses, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/76177244

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use MOXy to handle both the XML and JSON binding aspects of this use case.  As I mentioned in my comment MOXy supports the `XMLGregorianCalendar` type.  The Metadata would look like:

**EmpRequest**

```
package forum7725188;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="EmpRequest")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EmpRequest {

    @XmlElement(name="EmplIn")
    private EmplIn emplIn;

}
```

**EmplIn**

```
package forum7725188;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EmplIn {

    @XmlElement(name="EmpID")
    private long empId;

    @XmlElement(name="Empname")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name="Designation")
    private String designation;

    @XmlElement(name="DOJ")
    private XMLGregorianCalendar doj;

}
```

**package-info**

```
@XmlSchema(namespace="http://java.com/Employee", elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
package forum7725188;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**Demo**

You can configure the MOXy implementation of `Marshaller` to output JSON by setting the `eclipselink.media-type` property to be `application/json`.

```
package forum7725188;

import java.io.File;   
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(EmpRequest.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum7725188/input.xml");
        EmpRequest empRequest = (EmpRequest) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        JAXBElement<EmpRequest> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<EmpRequest>(new QName(""), EmpRequest.class, empRequest);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmpRequest xmlns="http://java.com/Employee">
    <EmplIn>
        <EmpID>12</EmpID>
        <Empname>sara</Empname>
        <Designation>SA</Designation>
        <DOJ>2002-05-30T09:30:10+06:00</DOJ>
    </EmplIn>
</EmpRequest>
```

**Output**

```
{"EmplIn" : 
   {"EmpID" : "12",
   "Empname" : "sara",
   "Designation" : "SA",
   "DOJ" : "2002-05-30T09:30:10+06:00"}}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/binding-to-json-xml-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

Comment: Thank you so much, Blaise. But sounds I need GAXB generated Java Pojos to be used for getting other resources of my application. Is theer any possiblity to use it with the GAXB generated Pojos?

Comment: @harish.raj - By `GAXB` do you mean `JAXB`?  If so then yes.  There isn't a real difference between generated classes or classes you annotate yourself as far as a JAXB runtime is concerned.

Comment: Blaise, I use Jdeveloper. and I get the following error. 
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: eclipselink.media-type value: application/json
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.setProperty(JAXBMarshaller.java:520)
 at com.moxy.employee.Test.main(Test.java:18)

Can you tell me how I can install/configure EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) so that it would be working fine.

Comment: @harish.raj - You need to use EclipseLink 2.4.  You can obtain a milestone release from:  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/milestones.php

Comment: I am also getting this exception, but I'm using 2.4.0-SNAPSHOT. Any suggestions?