# JsonException during converting Java object to JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Somehow below code is failing even after creating a custom type adapter. Its working for other type like string. Any idea how can I resolve the issue. Below is the code:

```
package com;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

public class DateConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {

        XMLGregorianCalendar date = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar();

        Request req = new Request();
        req.setDate(date);
        TypeAdapter<XMLGregorianCalendar> adapter = new TypeAdapter<XMLGregorianCalendar>() {

            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter writer, XMLGregorianCalendar value) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("Inside write");
                if(value==null) {
                    writer.nullValue();
                    return;
                }
                writer.value("value");

            }

            @Override
            public XMLGregorianCalendar read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("Inside read");
                return null;
            }
        };
        Gson gsonBuilder = (new GsonBuilder()).registerTypeAdapter(XMLGregorianCalendar.class, adapter).serializeNulls().create();
        System.out.println(gsonBuilder.toJson(req));
    }

}

class Request {
    private XMLGregorianCalendar date;

    public XMLGregorianCalendar getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(XMLGregorianCalendar date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

And below is the error stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl#eon' accessible; either change its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type
```

Java object should be successfully parsed to JSON but it is not working

Comment: Why are you importing xml data types to use with json? Use LocalDate to get calendar information

Comment: No I have one java class which has date attribute of this XMLGregorianCalendar type. So I just created one sample code as I can't paste entire code here. But its a java bean object that I want to convert to JSON. And worst part is this is existing code so I can't change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why Gson is unable to make fields of that class accessible is a combination of the [JDK restricting access to implementation details](https://openjdk.org/jeps/403) and Gson not having a built-in adapter for `XMLGregorianCalendar` so it falls back to using reflection.

Though it sounds your question is rather why your custom adapter is not called. The answer for this is most likely that (as seen in the exception message) you are not actually serializing an object of type `XMLGregorianCalendar`, but a JDK internal subclass. However, `GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter` which you are using registers the adapter for *that specific class* and not for subclasses.

To solve this you should use [`GsonBuilder.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(java.lang.Class,java.lang.Object)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are using Java 17+.

As of Java 17, the module system is enforced and java-xml doesn't export the internal classes for other modules to use.

See: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/74007890bb9a3fa3a65683a3f480e399f2b1a0b6/src/java.xml/share/classes/module-info.java

This is why `XMLGregorianCalendarImpl`'s fields are not available to the `GsonBuilder`.

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/74007890bb9a3fa3a65683a3f480e399f2b1a0b6/src/java.xml/share/classes/com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/jaxp/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java

I don't think that `GsonBuilder` can use an object's getters and setters.

So you need to make a proper TypeAdapter should map all the getters and setters in `XMLGregorianCalendar` to an object that can be serialized, something like `LocalDate`.

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/74007890bb9a3fa3a65683a3f480e399f2b1a0b6/src/java.xml/share/classes/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.java

Or you simply switch from `XMLGregorianCalendar` to `LocalDate`?

Comment: Nope. Didn't work

Comment: Is `XMLGregorianCalendar` public and do all of it's values have getter/setters?

Comment: Neither XMLGregorianCalendar nor XMLGregorianCalendarImpl are custom code. It's just some class provided by jdk.